# javascript action to trigger an event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been working on this for a while.  But I think it is going to be difficult for me to simply it for this question.

I have this object.  It is a child to an other object.

The child object has an 'action' attribute which executes a fn();
On a mouse click I fire off the action I can see I am executing fn() with no problems.

I want fn() to trigger an event of the parent object.

```
$('#par).on('trgr.obj', fn(e, dta) { alert('success'); });
$('#par').obj({
    chi: { action: fn(dta) {
        console.log("doing okay so far");
        // Here is where I'm trying to trigger trgr.obj event
        // this is what I have so far.
        var inst = $.obj.reference(dta.reference);
        var objT = inst.get_node(dta.reference);
        inst.trgr(
            objT, { type: "default" }, "last"
            , function (newDta) {
               setTimeout(function () { inst.edit(newDta); }, 0);
            }
        );
    }}
});
```

How does action trigger event 'trgr.obj'?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for jQuery to trigger a custom event?
Try `$('#par').trigger('trgr.obj')`

http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: I knew it had to be something super simple.  Thanks.